# Trouble printing from C++ file in VS Code when file uses a GSL function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gsl

I am trying to run an example script in C++ using GSL functions. I am using Visual Studio Code to compile and execute the program. The example code is below (I saved it under the file name gsl_bessel_example.cpp) and I got it directly from the GSL 2.7 Scientific Library documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html#an-example-program).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl\gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  //double y = 10.0;
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to output the following to the terminal after I have compiled and executed the program:

*J0(5) = -1.775967713143382642e-01*

When I compile the program, I use the following in the command line:

```
g++ -Wall gsl_bessel_example.cpp -IC:\msys64\mingw\include -LC:\msys64\mingw\lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

and execute it with:

```
.\a.exe
```

There are no errors or warnings given when I compile the file -- it compiles fine. However, I do not get any output when I execute it. If I comment out the line:

```
double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
```

and use:

```
double y = 10;
```

instead then recompile and execute, I receive an output I expect (see attached images for the results). Does anyone know why the file will not execute as expected when I use the GSL function? I have tried this for other examples provided in the GSL documentation but have similar results for all (no output).

[Image of Code and Output Using GSL Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3p8w.png)

[Image of Code and Output Not Using GSL Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj7bF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might be a bit late but I encountered the same problem and thought I'd share my solution.

Problem: the compiled binary cannot find the linked `libgsl.dll` and `libgslcblas.dll` libraries

Solution:

- Add the `<gsl-path>\gsl\bin` path to the `PATH` environment variable
- Restart all terminals

Here are the steps I took to find what the issue was:

- I compiled the source both with 32-bit gcc/GSL (installed from [here](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm)) and 64-bit gcc/GSL (installed with vcpkg).
- I ran the executable in WSL, and it gave me an error of "libgsl.dll not found".
- I placed the `libgsl.dll` and `libgslblas.dll` files found in `<gsl-path>\ gsl\bin` in the same directory of the .exe and it worked
- I checked if I had not added the `gsl\bin` folder to `PATH` environment variable
- It was already added, so I had to restart all terminals to make it work.

I hope it helps.